# How does one omit Excel VB parameters in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I am trying to import a tab delimited file into excel using powershell. Some of my numbers are very long and I need to import them as text to preserve them. I made an Excel Macro of the process and I want to incorporate the "Preserve Formatting" parameter. Everything in the macro from .TextFileStartRow = 1 till the end is represented in the powershell script but earlier parameters are omitted.

How do I communicate to skip those parameters?
Is there a way to preserve the format using the [blahblah.interop.excel]::____ format and insert one line in?

Below is my powershell and further down is a snippet from the macro

```
$thing = "C:\Users\michaelw\Desktop\Nasty 19\Testfile.txt" #where the original files are

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

        $wb = $excel.Workbooks.OpenText(                
        $thing, # file to open
        [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform]::xlWindows, 
         1, # start from row 1
      [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType]::xlDelimited,
                [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier]::xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
         $false, # Consecutive Delimiter
        $true, # tab
         $false, # semicolon
         $false, # comma
         $false, # space
         $false,  # use other
         '|')
```

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\michaelw\Desktop\Nasty 19\Testfile.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "Testfile"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working in one of my scripts...

```
$dataSheet = $wbObj.Worksheets.Item(1)
$dataSheet.Name = "Data"
$qryConn = ("TEXT;" + $csvPath)
$qryDest = $dataSheet.Range("A1")
$conn = $dataSheet.QueryTables.Add($qryConn,$qryDest)
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $true
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).TextFileParseType  = 1
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).FillAdjacentFormulas = $true
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
[void]$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).Refresh()
```

I'd think you could replace `TextFileCommaDelimiter` with `TextFileTabDelimiter` and make it work. Your best bet is to try and do it piece mail rather than all on one line.

Comment: It imported the files but the cells were in the "general" format (not the "text" format and it still turned long numbers into scientific notation. I even added this line. What am I doing wrong?

$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).preserveformatting  = 1

Comment: I'm guessing you want to bring in the line with TextFileColumnDataTypes...?

Comment: I later tried putting this in but it didn't work. Do I need to specify each column or is there a way to say do this for all columns?
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).textfilecolumndatatypes  = "xlTextFormat"

Comment: I think you need to set it to the value of the xlTextFormat constant, which I think is 2. This might help a bit: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/06/27/how-can-i-prevent-excel-from-turning-my-imported-numbers-into-dates.aspx

Comment: I added a line showing how I think it should work. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: The "Array" part trips it up; "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."  Could it be due to my using powershell 2?

Comment: I think I got it to work. You don't even need the word array! Thank you so much